# Disable scrolling from bottom to top in swiftUI scroll view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

In my iOS app (which is using SwiftUI) I am using a scroll view in which there is vertical scrolling. My issue is: I want to scroll only from top to bottom, and not bottom to top.

Is that possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use  [LazyVGrid](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/lazyvgrid)
and [DragGesture](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/draggesture)
when changed, you only allow scroll to bottom.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var offset: CGFloat = .zero
    
    var columns: [GridItem] = Array(repeating: .init(.flexible()), count: 2)
    var body: some View {
        LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
            ForEach((0...79), id: \.self) {
                let codepoint = $0 + 0x1f600
                let codepointString = String(format: "%02X", codepoint)
                Text("\(codepointString)")
                let emoji = String(Character(UnicodeScalar(codepoint)!))
                Text("\(emoji)")
            }
        }
        .font(.largeTitle)
        .offset(y: offset)
        .gesture(DragGesture().onChanged {value in
            let translation = value.translation.height
            if translation < 1 {
                offset = translation
            }
        })
    }
}
```

#### Update

You need to track the last offset when scrolling and reset it to zero each time you stop scrolling. This fixes the issue you have addressed in your comment.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var offset: CGFloat = .zero
    @State private var lastOffset: CGFloat = .zero
    
    var columns: [GridItem] = Array(repeating: .init(.flexible()), count: 2)
    var body: some View {
        LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
            ForEach((0...79), id: \.self) {
                let codepoint = $0 + 0x1f600
                let codepointString = String(format: "%02X", codepoint)
                Text("\(codepointString)")
                let emoji = String(Character(UnicodeScalar(codepoint)!))
                Text("\(emoji)")
            }
        }
        .font(.largeTitle)
        .offset(y: offset)
        .gesture(DragGesture().onChanged {value in
            let translation = value.translation.height
            if  translation <= lastOffset {
                offset = translation
                lastOffset = translation
            }
        }.onEnded { value in
            lastOffset = .zero
        })
    }
}
```

You do not need to use `LazyVGrid` if you your Views are not too many.

Comment: Issue with the solution that you can move on both direction when we scroll down and without removing the finger scroll up

Comment: @DhadTester fixed it. If  this helps, accept and upvote. so that others understand  this answer fixes the issue.

Comment: @DhadTester Really, you do not need to thank me. If it works for you, accep the answer.